# Why does writing to an Excel range take much longer than expected in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, excel, performance, save

I've built a script in C# that takes a large data file in CSV format and splits in into two output files in Excel 2007+ format.  I have fully working code that meets all the requirements, but it takes ~15 seconds to run my `save_files()` method on a relatively small source file.  I would like to know if there is a faster way to do what I'm doing.

The first output ends up writing up to 180 columns of 125,000 points each into an excel file.  (The 15 second run of the code used only 20 columns).  `output1_temp_array` is a `List<string[,]>` with each list item containing a string array with the 125k data points.  (It's defined as a 2D array because Excel's `Range.Value2` expects a 2D array, but really it's 125k x 1 item wide.)

The second output ends up writing 195 columns by 1 row.  The way `data_temp_array` is populated (it's also a `List<string[,]`), I have to transpose it into `temp_array`, and then write that temp_array into the Excel range.

Here's some of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using MyExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace TransposeAThing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void save_files()
        {
            MyExcel.Application excelApp = null;
            MyExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
            MyExcel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
            MyExcel.Range range = null;
            excelApp = new MyExcel.Application();
            excelApp.DefaultSaveFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook;
            excelApp.Visible = false;

            //Write data into first output file
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsOutput1_Filename, 1, false, 5, "", "", false, MyExcel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Output Data");

            for (int i = 0; i < output1_temp_array.Count(); i++)
            {
                range = worksheet.get_Range((MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, i + 2], (MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[output1_temp_array[i].Length, i + 2]);
                range.set_Value(Type.Missing,output1_temp_array[i]);
            }
            excelWorkbook.Save();
            excelWorkbook.Close();

            //Write data into second output file
            string[,] temp_array;
            temp_array = new string[1,data_temp_array.Count()];

            for (int i = 0; i < data_temp_array.Count(); i++)
            {
                temp_array[0,i] = data_temp_array[i][0,0];
            }

            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsData_Filename, 1, false, 5, "", "", false, MyExcel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Aggregate Data");

            int start_row = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;
            range = worksheet.get_Range((MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[start_row, 1], (MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[start_row, worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count]);

            range.Value2 = temp_array;
            excelWorkbook.Save();

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            if (worksheet != null)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            }
            if (excelWorkbook != null)
            {
                excelWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
            }
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                excelApp.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it takes so long to complete this process?  Any tips on how to speed it up?

For reference, a Python script I wrote to do the same thing takes about 2.3 seconds on the same data, so I know this could be faster than it is now.

Comment: Have you considered using the OpenXML SDK rather than COM? It is likely to be faster since it doesn't have to open excel. Obviously that would mean a significant refactor, but worth considering if you have performance issues.

Comment: I agree with Greg, using Openxml is a better way. If it doesn't need too much refactoring you might want to go the openxml way.

Comment: Do you know which part of your code is the bottleneck? Is it building the data? Writing to the file? A little profiling would help you narrow things down.

Comment: I'll look into OpenXML.  The code I posted pretty much is the bottleneck; all the code that builds the arrays takes less than half a second (including reading all 15MB+ of data from the CSV into a source array).  Even when I commented out the output1 write, it took 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after *MUCH* digging into OpenXML, I went with a kind of hybrid solution, which doesn't really solve the issue, but makes it faster at least.

For the first output file, I'm stuck with the original approach.  I tried out [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/) and found that there is no `writerow` or `range.setValue()` method, so writing a lot of cells ended up as nested `for` loops.  This proved to be *very* slow.

```
private void save_files()
{
    MyExcel.Application excelApp = null;
    MyExcel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
    MyExcel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    MyExcel.Range range = null;
    excelApp = new MyExcel.Application();
    excelApp.DefaultSaveFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook;
    excelApp.Visible = false;

    excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsOutput1_Filename, 1, false, 5, "", "", false, MyExcel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
    worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Output Data");

    for (int i = 0; i < output1_temp_array.Count(); i++)
    {
        range = worksheet.get_Range((MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, i + 2], (MyExcel.Range)worksheet.Cells[output1_temp_array[i].Length, i + 2]);
        range.set_Value(Type.Missing, output1_temp_array[i]);
    }
    excelWorkbook.Save();
    excelWorkbook.Close();
```

For the second data output, however, SpreadsheetLight definitely cut the time down:

```
    SLDocument data_file = new SLDocument(xlsData_Filename, "Aggregate Data");
    SLWorksheetStatistics data_file_info = new SLWorksheetStatistics();
    data_file_info = data_file.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    int start_row = data_file_info.NumberOfRows + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < data_temp_array.Count(); i++)
    {
        data_file.SetCellValue(start_row, i + 1, data_temp_array[i]);
    }
}
```

With this solution, the same files now take 8.5 seconds to generate instead of 15.